# Is it a good habit to omit dot and parentheses when writing Scala code?

Tags: scala

I am always wondering why Scala is designed to be able to omit dot and parentheses. This confuses me. For example,

```
"hello".length() can be written as
"hello".length
```

It creates confusion: in the point view of C++ coders,

```
"hello".length() is calling the object's length() function
"hello".length is calling the object's private/public variable.
```

They are different at all.

Also, it is wired to read the code without dot like this:

```
val myStr="hello world"
myStr substring(0, 3) toUpperCase() indexOf "h"
```

It looks like the sentence has not finished yet. It doesn't save space also, we still have to use blank " " instead of ".".

What is the purpose that Scala designers "invent" such omissions? Are we encouraged to use this style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, yes.  Methods with no parameters and have no side effects are recommended to be used without parenthesis.  If there are side effects use parenthesis.

The idea is, it doesn't matter if `length` is a method or accessing a property directly.  Either way, it just gives you the length and there is no fundamental difference to what you are doing which is just getting a value and it doesn't matter it is defined.  By convention the parenthesis indicate that there is some side effect going on, like printing to stdout or mutating a value.

For you second example, yes it would be quite weird to write code like that, but infix notation can be very useful.

For example, you can write `1 + 2` instead of `1.+(2)`. I think you can agree the first is preferable. It also opens up possibilities for writing nice looking DSLs that don't need the dots and parenthesis which was one of the goals.  In typical use however I would avoid it for non-symbolic (english) methods.

Answer (score 4):

Concerning parentheses, see "Parentheses" under http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html. "Methods which act as accessors of any sort (either encapsulating a field or a logical property) should be declared without parentheses except if they have side effects". For method invocation (with/out dots), see http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html. It is generally recommended to use dots, to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The optional usage of parenthesis is because of the [uniform access principle](http://pedrorijo.com/blog/fp-concepts/#uniform-access-principle) which states:

> All services offered by a module should be available through a uniform
>   notation, which does not betray whether they are implemented through
>   storage or through computation

In practice this means that the syntax used to manipulate attributes (stored) and methods (computations) should be the same

This principle also brings some eventual problems: if you are accessing a value that requires an expensive computation (an heavy database query for instance) and you are not aware of the cost, the system may become slow.

Sometimes you don’t care about the implementation underneath, and sometimes you have to be aware of it.